# chef setup: trying to start node app with PM2

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, pm2

I'm using the `nodejs` cookbook to install `node` and `PM2` module.

```
include_recipe "nodejs"
nodejs_npm "pm2"
```

So far, so good. But when I try to start my node app via PM2 with a process.json file it starts but isn't listed in the PM2 output when I ssh into the machine and run `pm2 list` ... very irritating.

Am I doing something wrong is it correct to not show up there?

```
execute "start node app via PM2" do
  cwd "/share/app"
  command "pm2 startOrRestart process.json"
end
```

and the `process.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "script": "src/index.js",
      "watch": true,
      "ignore_watch": ["[\\/\\\\]\\./", "node_modules"],
      "merge_logs": true,
      "exec_interpreter": "node",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "local",
        "port": 8080
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have the chef client log trace of executing resource "start node app via PM2"? Does it work if you run the command in a ssh session?

Comment: @JavierCortejoso it only says `execute[start node app via PM2] ran successfully`

Comment: It's because you started the process.json with another user, then when you ssh and do a pm2 list, it only list your current process users.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you started the process.json with another user, then when you ssh and do a pm2 list, it only list your current process users.

To avoid that you have two choices:

- Do the `pm2 start process.json` with the **same user**
- Set the PM2_HOME environment variable so all users will hit the same PM2 instance. Eg `PM2_HOME='/etc/.pm2' pm2 start process.json && PM2_HOME='/etc/.pm2' pm2 list`